# How to select text in silverlight 3.0 text block

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Is it possible to allow a user to select text in a silverlight text block (not text box) as they would be able to in any HTML page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  The Silverlight TextBlock doesn't support selection.  You would need to use a TextBox in read-only mode instead.  To make the user experience a bit more seamless, you could style the TextBox to have a normal arrow cursor instead of an I-beam.

Comment: That's what I keep reading.  I was hoping that someone was able to do something better by using a behavior or something.

Comment: @Gabriel I had the same hopes, but unfortunately you can't.  The TextBlock doesn't render text in the same way that a TextBox does.

Answer (score 18):

I later found a solution, and I wanted to share it.  The solution can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/bc03440d-a5b5-40c9-9ff0-9dc81741bf66/).

Excerpt from that page:

...change the textbox's style. Put the following Xaml code in App.xaml or some other resource:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">       
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderThickness="0"/>       
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then set your textbox's style as "{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}", and set IsReadOnly property as true, your textbox will look like a textblock but it can be copied.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore, and this is a solution for `TextBox`. OP clearly says `TextBlock`

Comment: @Julien: I updated the link.  If you look, I am the OP.  I asked, and it was answered that there was no actual text block solution.  It was a correct answer. That is why I accepted it.  I found a work-around, and I posted it here.  The work-around uses a textbox, styled to look and function like a text block (except that it allows the user to select and copy text).